# c++ Linker library error

Tags: c++

I tried to convert a program t obuilt with static library but it

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp___invalid_parameter        referenced in function "void * __cdecl std::_Allocate(unsigned int,unsigned    int,bool)" (?_Allocate@std@@YAPAXII_N@Z) WebBrowser embedded C:\user\Program.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___invalid_parameter    WebBrowser embedded C:\user\WebBrowser.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "void * __cdecl std::_Allocate(unsigned int,unsigned int,bool)" (?_Allocate@std@@YAPAXII_N@Z)   WebBrowser embedded C:\user\Program.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW    WebBrowser embedded C:\user\WebBrowser.obj  1
Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  WebBrowser embedded C:\user\web.exe 1
```

Iam using  Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) in Runtime-Library.

All helps are appreciated.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ please post the link of question.

Comment: It's just displayed at the top of yours. Click the refresh buttonn of your browser please.